# was vs had been unemployed for seven months

Tags: tense, perfect-constructions

My friend gave me three sentences and asked me to explain the difference. I have written them below.

(1) Ten months ago, John **was** unemployed for seven months.

(2) Ten months ago, John **had been** unemployed for seven months.

(3) Since ten months ago, John **had been** unemployed for seven months. The next month, he found a job.

I think (1) and (3) mean the same thing. I think (2) suggests that he got a job in the eighth month. Please give me your feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first example is not quite right. We can use *was* when we are talking about John's state at a point in time:

> Ten months ago *(we are thinking about a particular point in time)* John was living in London.
>
> Ten months ago John was single.
>
> Ten months ago John was a chef.
>
> Ten months ago John was unemployed.

Note that in the last example we talk about his being unemployed at that point in time.

When we talk about a condition that lasts for an extended period we need to position that activity relative to the point in time. We use **had been** to indicate that the activity completed at the point in time under consideration.

> Ten months ago John had been working as a chef for 3 months.
>
> Ten months ago John had been unemployed for 7 months.

In these cases there is a very strong implication that something changed at the point in time.

> Ten months ago John had been unemployed for 7 months. However, he found a position at XXX and has been working full-time since then.